# Session evict and merge for entity update

Tags: nhibernate, data-access-layer

I found this piece of code:

```
    public virtual void Update(T entity) {
        Logger.Debug("Update {0}", entity);
        Session.Evict(entity);
        Session.Merge(entity);
    }
```

Can you explain what are pros and cons of calling this over calling update on session? 
Why is this working, what are mechanics behind this code? Is it not too hacky?

Comment: Any reason why you aren't simply calling `Update` on the entity?

Comment: yeah thats exacly may question, why don't simply call update? it's fragment of external framework code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session.Evict` will evicts a single object from the session, for sample, if you already have an `obj`  on the session and you try to call `session.Update(entity)` you will get an exception saying that this `obj` is on the session and you cannot update.

`Session.Merge` will merge an single object with the existent object on the session (cache) and update.

take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9161057/316799

Comment: But why `merge()`? Why not follow eviction by direct update? Will update put entity not into session?

Comment: Following evict with direct update will still throw an `NonUniqueObjectException`. As documentation says the passed instance is removed not the object with the identifier and type.